# jquery how to detect form id in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a web page which has two forms.

like this:

```
<div class="ApartmentOwnerRegister">
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterApartmentOwner", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
    <p>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first Name" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last Name" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"  class="submit"/>
    </p>
    }
</div>
<div class="TenantRegister">
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterTenant", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
    <p>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first Name" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last Name" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Passport Number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your passport number" />
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="file">Upload You Passport:</label> 
        <input type="file" name="file" id="passport" style="width: 100%;" />  
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="file">Upload You Image:</label> 
        <input type="file" name="file" id="image" style="width: 100%;" />  
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"  class="submit"/>
    </p>
}
    </div>
```

what the user submit the form, i want to trigger a jquery function.

in the past, without mvc, i was doing this:

```
$("#formID").on('submit',function (e){});
```

but in that code what should i do instead of `formID` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".TenantRegister form").on('submit', function (e) {});
});
```

Referring to your HTML below in OP's posted Code

```
<div class="TenantRegister">
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterTenant", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
```

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli use `$(document).ready(function () {` Check updated answer .

Comment: i got exception because the controler is not existed yet. but i make three alert statments in the functoin, with a breaking point in the second one. However, nothing has been alerted, why please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yeah i think i need rest. I am making mess .

Answer (score 2):

You can use id in your `Html.BeginForm` like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterTenant", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formID", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and Jquery

```
$("#formID").on('submit',function (e){});
```

I guess this is the one you are looking for